# Proof that the sequence $ \{g \circ f_{n} \} $ converges uniformly in compact subsets of $ \Omega $ to the function $ g \circ f $.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \Omega $ be an open in $\mathbb{C}$, $\{f_{n} \}$ a succession of continuous functions of $\Omega$ in $ \mathbb{C}$ that converge to a
function $ f $ uniformly in compact subsets of $ \Omega $. Let $ g $ be a continuous function on $ \mathbb{C} $. Proof that the sequence $ \{g \circ f_{n} \} $ converges uniformly in compact subsets of $ \Omega $ to the function $ g \circ f $.

I tried to make this demonstration absurd but the test turned out to be a little difficult. I would like to know if there is a simpler test to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $K$ compact. There is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_K<1$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus, for all $n\geq N$, the range of $f_n$ over $K$ is contained in the closed ball $B$ around $0$ of radius $\|f\|_K +1$ which is compact in $\mathbb{C}$.

$g$, being continuous in $\mathbb{C}$, is uniformly continuous on $B$. Thus, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|g(y)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta $ and $x,y\in B$.

On the oner hand, there is $N^*\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq \max(N,N^*)$ implies that $\|f_n-f\|_K<\delta$

Consequently 
$$
|g(f_n(u))-g(f(v))|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $u,v\in K$.